# "Cannot access a disposed context instance" with PooledDbContextFactory

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I keep getting the error, and i can not figure out why as i have double verified my awaits are correct and that i am using the using parmeter. `Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.`

My Repository:

```
public class AccountRepository : IAccountRepository
{
    private readonly IAccountFactory accountFactory;
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<MagicContext> contextFactory;

    public AccountRepository(IDbContextFactory<MagicContext> context, IAccountFactory accountFactory)
    {
        this.contextFactory = context;
        this.accountFactory = accountFactory;
    }

    public async Task<List<Account>> GetUsersByEmailAsync(string email)
    {
        Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(email);
        await using MagicContext context = await this.contextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();
        return await context.Accounts
            .Where(x => x.Email == email)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Select(x => this.accountFactory.From(x))
            .ToListAsync();
    }
```

The accountFactroy is super simple and is just moving the values:

```
public class AccountFactory : IAccountFactory
{
    public Account From(AccountDal dal)
    {
        return new Account
        {
            Id = dal.Id,
            CompanyId = dal.CompanyId,
            Email = dal.Email,
            Password = dal.Password,
            AccountType = dal.AccountType,
            Name = dal.Name,
            CreatedMilliseconds = dal.CreatedMilliseconds,
            UpdatedMilliseconds = dal.UpdatedMilliseconds,
            LastSeenMilliseconds = dal.LastSeenMilliseconds,
        };
    }
}
```

My Service class:

```
public class AuthService : IAuthService
{
    private static readonly Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private readonly IAccountRepository accountRepository;
    private readonly ICompanyRepository companyRepository;

    public AuthService(IAccountRepository accountRepository, ICompanyRepository companyRepository)
    {
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
        this.companyRepository = companyRepository;
    }

    public async Task<AuthResult?> AuthUser(string email, string password, long? companyId)
    {
        Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(email);
        Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(password);
        if (companyId != null)
        {
            Guard.Against.Zero((long)companyId);
        }

        List<Account> accounts = await this.accountRepository.GetUsersByEmailAsync(email);
        // It throws the exception on the line above so the rest of the code dose not matter
    }
```

My controller:

```
public class AuthController : MagicBaseController
{
    private static readonly Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    private readonly IAccountRepository accountRepository;
    private readonly IAuthService authService;
    private readonly ICompanyRepository companyRepository;
    private readonly IKeyGenService keyGenService;

    public AuthController(IAuthService authService, IKeyGenService keyGenService, IAccountRepository accountRepository, ICompanyRepository companyRepository)
    {
        this.authService = authService;
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
        this.companyRepository = companyRepository;
        this.keyGenService = keyGenService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(AuthResponse))]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict, Type = typeof(AuthResponse))]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized, Type = typeof(AuthResponse))]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Auth(AuthSignInRequest request)
    {
        log.Debug("Auth attempt from {0}", request.Email);
        AuthResult? authResult = await this.authService.AuthUser(request.Email, request.Password, request.CompanyId);
        // Fails on the line above
    }
```

How i create my ContextFactory and classes DI:

```
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer()
            .AddSwaggerGen()
            .AddHttpClient()
            .AddPooledDbContextFactory<MagicContext>(optionsBuilder =>
            {
                string connectionString =
                    $"Server={builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DB_HOST")};" +
                    $"Port={builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DB_PORT")};" +
                    $"Database={builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DB_NAME")};" +
                    $"Uid={builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DB_USER")};" +
                    $"Pwd={builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DB_PASSWORD")};" +
                    $"Pooling=True;";
                // TODO: Remove later
                log.Info("Connection string: " + connectionString);
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString))
                {
                    log.Error("Missing connection string");
                    throw new Exception("Missing connection string");
                }

                optionsBuilder.UseMySql(
                    connectionString,
                    MySqlServerVersion.LatestSupportedServerVersion
                );
                optionsBuilder.LogTo(message => log.Trace(message));
            }, 10)
            .AddSingleton<IKeyGenService, KeyGenService>(provider =>
            {
                // TODO: This needs to be fixed to use ZooKeeper to assign the worker id
                // Untilthen we hope we just don't get overlapping ids
                return new KeyGenService(new IdGenerator(Rand.RandomInt(0, 1024)));
            })
            .AddSingleton<IAccountFactory, AccountFactory>()
            .AddSingleton<ICompanyFactory, CompanyFactory>()
            .AddSingleton<IChatGPTUsageFactory, ChatGPTUsageFactory>()
            .AddScoped<IAccountRepository, AccountRepository>()
            .AddScoped<ICompanyRepository, CompanyRepository>()
            .AddScoped<IChatGPTRepository, ChatGPTRepository>()
            .AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>()
            .AddScoped<IAccountService, AccountService>()
```

My context:

```
public class MagicContext : DbContext
{
    public MagicContext(DbContextOptions<MagicContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<CompanyDal> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AccountDal> Accounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ChatGPTUsageDal> ChatGptUsage { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.HasCharSet("utf8mb4");
        modelBuilder.UseCollation("utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci");
    }
}
```

Update: The full stack trace:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you shoul
d let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
      Object name: 'MagicContext'.
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.CheckDisposed()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetInfrastructure[T](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, ModelCreationDependencies modelCreationDependencies, Boolean designTime)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel(Boolean designTime)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__8_4(IServiceProvider p)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__8_8(IServiceProvider p)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IResettableService.ResetState()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextPool`1.Return(IDbContextPoolable context)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextLease.Release()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextLease.ContextDisposed()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Dispose()
         at MagicDoor.Data.Repositories.AccountRepository.GetUsersByEmailAsync(String email) in C:\Users\Kasper Sogaard\workspace\portal-backend\MagicDoor.Data\Repositories\Accounts\AccountRepository.cs:line 35
         at MagicDoor.Library.Services.Accounts.AuthService.AuthUser(String email, String password, Nullable`1 companyId) in C:\Users\Kasper Sogaard\workspace\portal-backend\MagicDoor.Library\Services\Accounts\AuthService.cs:line 61
         at MagicDoor.Api.Controllers.AuthControllers.AuthController.Auth(AuthSignInRequest request) in C:\Users\Kasper Sogaard\workspace\portal-backend\MagicDoor.Api\Controllers\AuthControllers\AuthController.cs:line 56
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Update 2:
I found a solution i think? Going to leave it open as it still makes little sense to me.
I tried to go around the factory and instead did the AddDbContext, with that i got another error saying that it could not find "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" so i installed that package and not it workes with both the factory and AddDbContext.

Comment: It is an using declaration so this would first dispose of the context after the method had returned. Just to verify this i had also tried wrapping it in a `using () {}`, i had even tried not using the `using` at all and therefore not disposing of the context at all. All had the same error.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this code could work with the `Select` calling a factory like that. Since query isn't being materialized prior to that, I would expect EF to complain that it cannot translate that factory method call.  Perhaps try the same structure but using Automapper and it's ProjectTo method. Create a `var config = MapperConfiguration<AccountDao,Account>()` given your naming convention is consistent, then `return await context.Accounts.Where(x => x.Email == email).ProjectTo<Account>(config).ToListAsync();`

Comment: Also, does the exception happen in the Repository call or afterwards such as after the controller returns? If the later than it might be you have an Entity reference getting copied into your DTO (Account) with the main suspect being AccountType from your example. If AccountType happens to be a DAL entity then your Account DTO might need to extract the AccountTypeID and AccountTypeName etc. from the DAL. This error commonly appears when mixing entity references into DTOs.

Comment: I have added the full stack trace in the post. @StevePy i have used that pattern for years so it should work, but i did also test that by moving the select out to after the .ToListAsync() same issue.

Comment: Found out i was missing the dependency "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational"

Comment: Ah yes, EF Core's compartmentalization.. Several little pieces that if you miss adding one everything stops working. :)